# Unpopular answers that may be the correct ones

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

There were two similar questions that asked for two very similar sources.

[Where is it taught that Hashem doesn't give a person test that he can't overcome?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48784/where-is-it-taught-that-hashem-doesnt-give-a-person-test-that-he-cant-overcome)

and

[Source: God only gives people what they can handle](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66461/source-god-only-gives-people-what-they-can-handle)

My answer to both of these were similar because the questions were similar, and both were downvoted. But i don't think that they were downvoted because my answer didn't answer the question, nor were they downvoted because they were incorrect. i think they were downvoted because my answer states that the source for these statements come from Christianity, and that is an unpopular answer. But it is also the most truthful answer, all the other answers search for similar statements that when you look at them this way or that, you could claim its a source. But these statements have been a part of Christianity for a very long time, are publicized everywhere by Christians, and are now entering the mainstream Jewish fold.

But if people downvote my answer "because they don't like it or its implications," then it prevents the truth from being acknowledged and spreading. So should i not answer these questions truthfully? Do our guidelines need to be revised? What should happen?

Comment: To date, each of these answers has garnered one downvote. The voting you're talking about may not even have come from multiple people. Any voting is hard to pin down to specific "guidelines" or even specific reasons. A single downvote, all the more so, could have been nothing more than one person who happened to be in a bad mood today. Whatever it is, there's not enough data there to make any inferences about communal behavior or rules.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they were downvoted because they were incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

I've just reviewed the two questions you link.  Both of your answers say that "the" source is Christianity, yet four answers on the first question offer Jewish sources.  It's not surprising to me that people would downvote an answer that says that you have to go to Christianity for a source; that appears to be incorrect.  A suggestion that the rabbis who made the statements being asked about used Christian sources would need more support than you've offered so far.

People can of course downvote (or upvote) for any reason they like; we can't audit that.  But in my experience people downvote if they feel an answer is wrong, or if it doesn't support claims that call for support, or if it's terse (maybe it's right but it's an unsupported one-liner), or because they find it unhelpful for other reasons.  The tooltip for the downvote button simply says "this answer is not useful".

In my experience (not just on this site), the farther away from the mainstream an answer falls, the more work the answerer needs to do to persuade people of its correctness.  This makes sense whether we're talking about non-Jewish sources on Mi Yodeya, non-peer-reviewed sources on Physics, or personal anecdotes on Skeptics.

Finally, on *this* site you should expect claims from Christianity to garner extra scrutiny because of their institutions' long, long record of misreading, reinterpretation, and outright fraud concerning Judaism and Jews.